# How can an application detect that the hypervisor has resumed its guest OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, hyper-v

How can an application detect when the hypervisor has resumed its guest OS after suspending it due to, for example, migration? Is there an API for it, depending on the specific hypervisor, or is there something in the environment (Linux or Windows) that unambiguously indicates resumption?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really anything that I can think of off the top of my head. The guest OS, for the most part, doesn't really know it's virtualized so it doesn't have a concept of what host it's on or whether or not it's being migrated and/or suspended at the hypervisor level.

Is there a particular use case you can share where this would be helpful?

Comment: It's the missing-time problem. Guest wakes up, looks at the clock, and wonders where the last few seconds went. If it go, "Oh, I've been abducted by aliens!," I would be so happy. From my research, there is no way to unambiguously know this.